# nginx permission denied to certificate files for ssl configuration

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm installing an nginx ssl proxy on my Fedora server.

I've created a cert and key pair under /etc/nginx. They look like this:

```
ls -l /etc/nginx/
total 84
...
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1346 Sep 20 12:11 demo.crt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1679 Sep 20 12:11 demo.key

...
```

As root, I'm trying to start the nginx service:

```
systemctl start nginx.service
```

I get the following error:

```
nginx[30854]: nginx: [emerg]
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/nginx/demo.crt") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system     library:fopen:Permission denied...e:system lib)
nginx[30854]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Is there something wrong with the permissions on these files?

Comment: It mentions certificate chain... isn't the problem with certification authority of that demo.crt key? Or is it self-signed certificate? By the way, I don't think key file should be readable by world. Nginx should open it as root and then drop privileges to whatever user it runs as.

Comment: It's self-signed, yes. I will change the ownership, thanks.

Comment: You assume the problem is with the certificates, but the error message applies to the configuration file for Nginx.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You probably have SELinux in enforcing mode (the default for Fedora):

```
sestatus -v
```

If this is the case, check the audit logs, you should find the access error:

```
ausearch -m avc -ts today | audit2allow
```

You also probably moved the filed instead of copying it, so the security context of the file might be wrong.

```
ls -lrtZ /etc/nginx/demo.*
```

and correct it if needed:

```
restorecon -v -R /etc/nginx
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your instructions and I am no longer getting the error. I did happen to move these files from the directory in which I created them. I can create them in the same directory next time. Other than that, how do I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: For this specific use case, use `cp` instead of `mv` and learn to use the `audit` system to look for AVC denials.

Comment: The ausearch | audit2allow command. Did that add some permissions to selinux or was that just to confirm that selinux was the problem?

Comment: It was just to confirm. Read their respective manual pages for the details.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It's good to have an answer which isn't just 'disable SELinux'.

Comment: I have the very same error, but I doubt your solution applies to me: none of *all* the commands suggested there work for me. Using Ubuntu 14.04. You say >  "the security context of the file might be wrong", could be be more specific on this point?

Comment: The security context refers to the Mandatory Access Control of the file. It is relevant if you have a Linux Security Module active in your system. In the case of Ubuntu, that would normally be AppArmor, not SELinux.

Answer (score 13):

I guess it's SELinux that denies permission.  Check their SELinux context.  Theirs should be httpd_config_t.  If not, run

```
restorecon /etc/nginx/demo.*
```

or

```
chcon httpd_config_t /etc/nginx/demo.*
```

as root.

You can check logs under /var/log/audit/ to see if it's SELinux that denies permission.  You can also run

```
setenforce 0
```

to set SELinux into **permissive mode**.  This way, SELinux still generates AVC messages (in /var/log/audit/) but permits access.

Comment: you may need to supply the `-t` argument before the context for `chcon`

Comment: `setenforce 0` only solved the issue for me.

Comment: Also to set it permanently and to make it work after reboot edit this file `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set `SELINUX=disabled`