# nginx permission denied to self signed certificate files for ssl configuration on CentOs

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, openssl, selinux

Very similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/540537/nginx-permission-denied-to-certificate-files-for-ssl-configuration) but the solutions there did not solve my problem.

I am trying to reverse proxy port 8443 to port 4000 with a self signed certificate. I generated my certificate like this

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout certificate.key -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem`

And I added a server block to my nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 8443 ssl;
  server_name www.mydomain.io;
  ssl_certificate /home/user/certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/user/certificate.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

But now when I try to start nginx with `systemctl start nginx` I get the following error:

```
Sep 10 06:38:52 Elixir systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Sep 10 06:38:52 Elixir nginx[25347]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/home/user/certificate.pem") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/home/user/certificate.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
Sep 10 06:38:52 Elixir nginx[25347]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Edit: The files have 777 permissions but are not owned by the nginx user.

Comment: A very strong convention for services is to have their settings and configuration files in `/etc/` and not in your home directory. Second the first thing to investigate in a `fopen ... permission denied` type error are indeed the file system permissions for both the file and complete directory path as they apply to whatever user nginx runs as. ( your users home directories are typically closed to other users...)

Comment: I forgot to add that I made the .key and .pem files have 777 permissions

Comment: 777, That's too much! And. .. You also need to check the permissions on the **full directory path** I.e. `/home/ & /home/user/` and not just those on the certificate and key..

Comment: Move didn't solve my problem. If it is for the full path wouldn't nginx have to belong to the root group? Permissions for /etc/ `drwxr-xr-x root  root etc`.

Comment: nvm, It does have read access for everyone. Move + the other questions answers still didn't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was very likely due to selinux labeling the file as something insecure like `unconfined_u` therefore denying access to it no matter what the permissions of the file are. The labels for a file can be checked by running `ls -Z`.

The solution is to change the label (aka [selinux context](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files)) of the file to something that nginx permitted to open:

```sh
chcon -t httpd_config_t /path/to/file
```

Comment: The answer is correct. I would anyway mention that this is "runtime" solution. With the first `restorecon` the changes will be reverted... To make it persistent you should add _record_ to fcontext using `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_config_t /path/to/file` and then you can run `restorecon -R -v /path/to/file` to apply the changes. In case you have already use `chcon` you don't need to run `restorecon` as it is already set up. The `semanage fcontext...` is the part making it persistent.

Answer (score 1):

A very strong convention for services is to have their settings and configuration files in `/etc/` and not in your home directory.

Second the first thing to investigate in a `fopen ... permission denied` type error are indeed the file system permissions for both **the file** and **complete directory path** as they apply to whatever user nginx runs as.

(Users home directories are typically closed to other users...)

Use [namei](http://linux.die.net/man/1/namei) to display the permissions of the full path:

```
namei -mov /home/user/certificate.pem
```

If the normal file system permissions are correct, then investigate further into for instance SELinux access controls as explained in the Q&A you linked to.