# nginx won't reload: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file failed

Tags: nginx, ssl

I was trying to increase client_max_body_size limits in my `nginx.conf` file, but after executing `service nginx restart`, the system returned an error:

```
2017/02/21 14:39:18 [emerg] 17371#0: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file
("/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsiteaddress.com/fullchain.pem")
failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission
denied error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib error:140DC002:SSL
routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have no idea what might be the issue. Can somebody please help me? Thank you!

Some [solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/540537/nginx-permission-denied-to-certificate-files-for-ssl-configuration) suggest to check `sestatus -v` - but all I get is `sestatus: command not found`

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Comment: I've tried running sestatus -v but all I get is sestatus: command not found

Comment: What are the permissions of the `fullchain.pem` file?

Comment: Thanks for replying, @TeroKilkanen! Shortcut of `fullchain.pem` (stored in `letsencrypt/live`) has permissions set at 777, `fullchain.pem` itself (stored in `letsencrypt/archive` is at 644

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part of the error message is **fopen:Permission
denied error:**.   It means that nginx server (which is usually running as nginx user) can't access certificate file in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsiteaddress.com/fullchain.pem`

As you already tested permissions of the file (its 0777), it probably means that nginx can't enter the directories on path.

You should check permissions on `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsiteaddress.com/`, `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` and `/etc/letsencrypt/` to verify that  nginx can enter the directories ([check this answer for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)).

If the directories don't have user nor group set to nginx, you can add the *enter directory permission* to others with

```
chmod o+X /etc/letsencrypt/DIRECTORY_NAME
```

If some of directories on the path are owned by `nginx` group (which probably should be), you should add *enter directory permission* to group with

```
chmod g+X /etc/letsencrypt/DIRECTORY_NAME
```

Other reasons which can generate *permission defined* are SELinux (but this is unprobable in Ubuntu 12 and you already checked it), chroot, and many others but these are also unprobable (and you would probably mention using some special configuration).