# NGINX SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, permissions, certificate

I have been stuck on this for ages and I'm hoping someone can offer some advice.

Trying to install a new SSL certificate on a site. On running `nginx -t` i get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite_com/mysite_com.crt") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite_com/mysite_com.crt','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Now I have set the owner/group on the mysite_com.crt to the same as the files that were in the previous config which pass the nginx test fine. I have also set the permissions to the same. Even setting the file permissions to 777 temporarily to test gave the same error. I also tried creating a /ssl/ directory in the root of the partition with 777 and still the same error. I have set the owner to `http` which is the webserver user on this machine and nothing.

I'm completley stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to check each element of the path, not only the filename. Each directory must have `rx` rights for the user under which your `nginx` process runs.

Comment: this worked for me I found this answer https://serverfault.com/a/540544

Answer (score 3):

There is only one suggestion, you don't have enough rights for access file `/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite_com/mysite_com.crt`. When you start `nginx -t` under your account, nginx started with your permissions and couldn't get access to this files. There is two ways how to fix this issue without changing anything. First one - run `nginx -t` under root account or trough sudo to test configuration, second one - run `nginx -t` under http account to see how nginx start in real environment. But if you would like to make changes, you could add your user to group http and try to run `nginx -t`.

Comment: Unfortunately everything on this server has to be done under sudo su as the ssh account has been locked down quite tightly. I will try running nginx -t under the http user to see if they gives me any luck.

Comment: @Craig have you disabled SELinux?

Comment: I did read another post suggesting sestatus -v which just came back with command not found.

Comment: @Craig what Linux you use?

Comment: Excellent question, I'm waiting for that answer myself. I did cat /proc/version and /etc/*-version and couldn't find any clues. With any luck when I find out it will give me a clue to what's going on.

Comment: @Craig try `cat /etc/*release*`

Comment: As it turns out it appears to be a Synology Device of some kind. Build 15101. Any quirks that this distribution has?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few hours to figure it out, so it might be helpful for someone else: if you see `error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied` and permissions are correct: check `apparmor`. Message in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
type=1400 audit(1629546067.301:14345): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="..." name="..." pid=704726 comm="..." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

To fix correct corresponding profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/`

Answer (score 0):

If you have already confirmed that the `chmod` and `chown` settings are correct for the file, another possible cause for the "fopen: Permission denied" error is related to SELinux. This issue might occur when you initially copied the file into a directory, such as the home folder, and then used the `mv` command to relocate the file into its final position for NGINX.

SELinux remembers the original file creation location and applies permissions based on that information, even after the file has been moved. To rectify this and align SELinux permissions with the current file location and permissions, you can use the following command:

```bash
restorecon -v /path/to/your/file
```

Replace "/path/to/your/file" with the actual path to your file. The `restorecon` command resets the SELinux context of the specified file or directory, bringing it in line with the current location.

By running this command, you can address potential SELinux-related permission issues that may persist after moving the file, ensuring that SELinux permissions match the actual file location and permissions.